# Convert a list of tuples into a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
mydata =[(22, 1),
         (22, 0),
         (22, 0),
         (22, 1),
         (23, 0),
         (23, 1),
         (23, 2),
         (23, 1),
         (23, 0),
         (24, 3),
         (24, 3),
         (24, 2),
         (24, 1),
         (24, 0)]
```

And I want to create a dictionary of lists based on the first items in the tuples. Something like:

```
mydict = {22: [1, 0, 0, 0], 23: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], 24: [3, 3, 2, 1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `itertools.groupby()` function:

```
import itertools

data = [(22,1), (22,0), (22,0), (22,1), (23,0), (23,1), (23,2), (23,1), (23,0), (24,3), (24,3), (24,2), (24,1), (24,0)]
result = {k: list(i[1] for i in g) 
             for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x[0])}
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{24: [0, 1, 2, 3, 3], 22: [0, 0, 1, 1], 23: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by folowing code

```
for i in mydata:
    if mydict.get(i[0], ''):
        mydict[i[0]] += ' ' + str(i[1])
    else:
        mydict[i[0]] = str(i[1])

print(mydict)
{'22': "1 0 0 0", '23':"0 1 2 1"}
```

This is if values of your dict - string

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop:

```
mydict = {}

for i in range(len(mydata)):
    mylist = mydict.get(mydata[i][0], [])
    mylist.append(mydata[i][1])
    mydict[mydata[i][0]] = mylist
```